# give user permissions to database

Tags: python, mysql, permissions

I've had a problem for days: I need a database that interacts with a Python program, but the database doesn't let me use the data from the database. Some people told me it was because of the user permissions of the database.
Does anyone know how I can assign permissions to let me work with Python?
Thanks

Comment: See this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300328/mysql-grant-user-permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to speak to the DBA that owns the database to be granted access and appropriate permissions to access tables.

If the DBA is you, I'd suggest that you start reading up on relational databases and MySQL in particular:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html

I'd recommend creating a username and password for each database.  Don't give any application root access.  I do it like this:

```
create database contacts;
create user contacts identified by 'contacts';
grant all on contacts.* to 'contacts'@'%';
grant select on `mysql`.`proc` to 'contacts'@'%';
use contacts;
```