How to copy data between databases using Laravel connections?
I'm working on a Laravel application where I need to copy data from one database to another using different database connections. I have two database connections set up, $defaultConnection and $stockConnection. I'm trying to copy data from the $defaultDatabase to the $stockDatabase. Here's the code I have:
$defaultConnection = 'mysql'; // Default connection name
$stockConnection = 'stock'; // stock connection name

$stockDatabase = config('database.connections.'.$stockConnection.'.database');
$defaultDatabase = config('database.connections.'.$defaultConnection.'.database');
    
// Copy data from the default database to the stock database
DB::connection($stockConnection )->statement("INSERT INTO `$stockDatabase `.`$table` ($columnNames) SELECT $columnNames FROM `$defaultDatabase`.`$table`");



I have got an error
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'stock_acc'@'localhost' for table 'activity_log' (Connection: stock, SQL: INSERT INTO `stock`.`activity_log` (`id`, `log_name`) SELECT `id`, `log_name` FROM `dev_db`.`activity_log`)

I'm trying to copy data  from defaultConnection to stockConnection  with same tables names
it work when I gave them same MySQL account but when I separate account and permission for every table I got this error

You need to grant permission to read the table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300328/mysql-grant-user-permission
